# ZAP reports there's a path traversal vulnerability. How it found it?

Tags: security, zap, path-traversal

I was testing a web application with ZAP and it reports a [path traversal vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504327/exploiting-and-correcting-path-traversal-vulnerability). I understand it how it works (at least, I think so), so I reviewed the code, tested the URLs, but I could not find where to fix the vulnerability. I only know from ZAP that the problem is only in the URL `/service/book` and the parameter `category`. It's interesting that the rest of the app does not have the same problem.

Maybe, if I know how ZAP found it, it will help me to understand where the problem is and fix the app. **Do you know how can I check what ZAP did to detect the vulnerability?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the source code for that test: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrules/TestPathTraversal.java

Does that help?

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: The link expired, do you have an updated link? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, more info about all ZAP alerts can now be found using their alert ID. The Path Traversal ID is 6 so its at https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/6/ - that links to the source near the end of the page.